# Query to select intervals in day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table something like this (there's also "device_id" and "timestamp" columns)

```
day  | interval  |  value
----------------------------
1    | 14        |  63  // start of a day
1    | 14        |  83
1    | 14        |  73

1    | 15        |  23
1    | 15        |  33
1    | 15        |  50

2    | 16        |  23  // start of a day
2    | 16        |  33
2    | 16        |  50
```

I want to select all intervals in a day. That is simple.

However, an interval can start a bit before a day flips, or end a bit past:

```
day  | interval  |  value
----------------------------
7    | 14        |  63
7    | 14        |  83
8    | 14        |  73  // start of a day

8    | 15        |  23
8    | 15        |  33
8    | 15        |  50

8    | 16        |  23
8    | 16        |  33
9    | 16        |  50  // start of a day
```

Now I'd like to select all three intervals - or even better intervals that are mostly in that day.

```
SELECT ... WHERE day = 8
```

Gives me only parts of the start/end intervals (14, 16). That's useless, I need the complete intervals.

If there's no solution, I'll just do three queries, but there might be some SQL trick I'm not aware of?

It's MySQL, called from PHP.

More visually:

```
  day 7           | day 8             | day 9
------------------+-------------------+---------------
   ###13###  ###14###  ###15###  ###16###   ###17###
        ...  63 83 73  23 33 50  23 33 50   ...
```

I want all values in day 8 -> intervals 14, 15, 16

Comment: Please illustrate the intented result - that's not really clear right now.

Comment: I want to have complete intervals, that are partially in the day.

Comment: This is a simple join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM intervals 
WHERE interval IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT interval FROM intervals WHERE day = 8)
```

This selects all interval data where at least one of the entries for that interval occurs in day 8. The subquery determines which unique intervals happen in the day, which is then used by the outer query to select their specifics.

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong, but I tried this and the php page totally froze. NB, the table has millions of rows...

Comment: This is the correct answer, but if you don't have separate indexes on `day` and `interval` and have millions of rows, you may have performance issues.  Post the query plan for this query if you want help analyzing the performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.some_column = x.some_column 
 WHERE x.some_other_column = 8;
```

Comment: Before I try this - can it realistically be faster than Niels's solution?

Comment: Duh, obviously if a day is 7 and then 8, it's not hard to figure out the day changed.

Comment: I've got also a timestamp column, and order by it... if that helps.

Comment: + they DO have order. MySQL keeps track of insertion order.

Comment: I suggest you amend your question to reflect that fact. And no, it doesn't

Comment: I don't have anything else to add to this

Comment: i asked something in chat yesterday, but you ignored it.. doesn't matter, really.

Comment: MySQL does ***not*** keep track of insertion order. It may appear to do so, but it's just filling pages sequentially. As your data grows and pages are reorganized, the order ***will*** break.